# Electron Context menu on dragable area

Tags: javascript, css, windows, electron

> Context menu On some platforms, the draggable area will be treated as
>   a non-client frame, so when you right click on it a system menu will
>   pop up. To make the context menu behave correctly on all platforms you
>   should never use a custom context menu on draggable areas.

Taken from https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/frameless-window.md

Is there a way to work around this. I need to have an image dragable and able to handle both click and right click events. (Much like Facebook messenger on mobile devices).

It setting an element as dragable (-webkit-app-region: drag;) and using context menu event works as expected in mac but when using the  build on windows it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to have `-webkit-app-region: drag;` and a context menu on Windows. That's because Windows displays its own context menu for these UI items.

[image]

Another option is [electron-drag](https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-drag) which can simulate `webkit-app-region`.

Comment: I tried hammer js. I added a pan event handler and moved the window. The problem now is the window is jumping all over the place. I followed this example https://codepen.io/bladnman/pen/LEWYYN and used `BrowserWindow.setPosition(ev.deltaX, ev.deltaY, true)`

Comment: Sorry, I should have posted that as a comment rather than an answer so I deleted it. The jitteriness is probably because the windows is being moved under the mouse which is causing more hammer events in the opposite direction or something like that. It might be easier to use this pre-existing module: https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-drag

Comment: I will look into that.

Comment: Can you update the answer so I can accept it. Electron Drag seems to solve this problem. (Not in my case) But if anyone have the same problem this will be helpfull.

Answer (score 0):

do some as below, use pointerevent to capture mouse outside of BrowserWindow

```
diff --git a/src/main/boot.coffee b/src/main/boot.coffee
index 4a42164..18242f8 100644
--- a/src/main/boot.coffee
+++ b/src/main/boot.coffee
@@ -69,7 +69,7 @@ do =>
     if v instanceof Function
       #if not isPackaged
       ipcMain.handle k.join('.'), (e,args)=>
-        v(...args)
+        v.apply(e,args)

     for [name,func] from Object.entries v
       _handle [...k, name], func
diff --git a/src/main/ipc.coffee b/src/main/ipc.coffee
index d912ee2..6084543 100644
--- a/src/main/ipc.coffee
+++ b/src/main/ipc.coffee
@@ -10,6 +10,7 @@ export {default as count_down} from './ipc/count_down.coffee'
 `export * as recbar from './ipc/recbar.coffee'`
 `export * as USER from './ipc/user.coffee'`
 `export * as camera from './ipc/camera.coffee'`
+`export * as drag from './ipc/drag.coffee'`

 export {default as area} from './ipc/area.coffee'
 export {default as main} from './ipc/main.coffee'
diff --git a/src/main/ipc/drag.coffee b/src/main/ipc/drag.coffee
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..6edd12d
--- /dev/null
+++ b/src/main/ipc/drag.coffee
@@ -0,0 +1,12 @@
+#!/usr/bin/env coffee
+
+export setBounds = (x,y,width,height)->
+  win = @sender.getOwnerBrowserWindow()
+  # not use setPosition because https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/9477 browserWindow.setPosition(x,y) changed window size (windows/linux) with non default scaleLevel (125% for example)
+  win.setBounds {
+    x:Math.round(x)
+    y:Math.round(y)
+    width
+    height
+  }
+  return
diff --git a/src/web/src/lib/_on.coffee b/src/web/src/lib/_on.coffee
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..31d8beb
--- /dev/null
+++ b/src/web/src/lib/_on.coffee
@@ -0,0 +1,6 @@
+export default (elem, dict)=>
+  for event,func of dict
+    elem.addEventListener(event, func)
+  =>
+    for event,func of dict
+      elem.removeEventListener(event, func)
diff --git a/src/web/src/lib/drag.coffee b/src/web/src/lib/drag.coffee
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..191aa1e
--- /dev/null
+++ b/src/web/src/lib/drag.coffee
@@ -0,0 +1,95 @@
+#!/usr/bin/env coffee
+
+#import {IS_WIN} from '~/lib/os.coffee'
+import $on from '~/lib/on.coffee'
+import ipc from '~/lib/ipc.coffee'
+
+{drag:{setBounds}} = ipc
+#IS_WIN = true
+pointermove = 'pointermove'
+IGNORE = new Set('SELECT BUTTON A INPUT TEXTAREA'.split ' ')
+{round} = Math
+export default main = (elem)=>
+  #if not IS_WIN
+  #  return
+
+  elem.style.appRegion = 'no-drag'
+
+  moving = false
+
+  init_w = init_h = init_x = init_y = init_top = init_left = undefined
+
+  _move = (e)=>
+    {screenX,screenY} = e
+    setBounds(
+      round screenX-init_x+init_left
+      round screenY-init_y+init_top
+      init_w
+      init_h
+    )
+    return
+
+  mousedown = (e)=>
+    if e.button!=0 # 鼠标左键
+      return
+    {target} = e
+    #if target.tagName != 'VIDEO'
+    #  return
+    p = e.target
+    loop
+      {nodeName} = p
+      if IGNORE.has nodeName
+        return
+      if nodeName == 'BODY'
+        break
+      p = p.parentNode
+    moving = true
+    {screenX:init_x,screenY:init_y} = e
+
+    elem.setPointerCapture e.pointerId
+    elem.addEventListener pointermove,_move
+
+    init_top = screenTop
+    init_left = screenLeft
+    init_w = outerWidth
+    init_h = outerHeight
+
+    return
+
+  mouseup = (e)=>
+    if moving
+      await _move(e)
+      elem.releasePointerCapture e.pointerId
+      elem.removeEventListener pointermove,_move
+      moving = false
+    return
+
+  $on elem,{
+    lostpointercapture:mouseup
+    pointercancel:mouseup
+    pointerdown:mousedown
+    pointerup:mouseup
+  }
+
+  return
+
+###
+    init_x = init_y = undefined
+
+
+    move = (e)=>
+      {screenX:x,screenY:y} = e
+      await camera.move(x-init_x,y-init_y)
+
+    mousemove = (e)=>
+      await move(e)
+      return
+
+
+
+      await camera.init()
+      moving = true
+
+      return
+
+###
diff --git a/src/web/src/lib/on.coffee b/src/web/src/lib/on.coffee
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..a79b9e7
--- /dev/null
+++ b/src/web/src/lib/on.coffee
@@ -0,0 +1,5 @@
+import $on from './_on.coffee'
+export default (elem, dict)=>
+  unbind = $on elem, dict
+  onUnmounted unbind
+  unbind
diff --git a/src/web/src/page/recbar.vue b/src/web/src/page/recbar.vue
index f853865..d6d6796 100644
--- a/src/web/src/page/recbar.vue
+++ b/src/web/src/page/recbar.vue
@@ -154,7 +154,7 @@ nav.pause > code, code.pause
     background-color transparent
 </style>
 <template lang="pug">
-nav(:class="{ pause }")
+nav(:class="{ pause }" ref="nav")
   template(v-for="([en, cn], pos) in left")
     a(:class="[en, config[en] ? '' : 'x']" :title="cn" @click="go(en)")
   b
@@ -178,7 +178,7 @@ import ipc from '~/lib/ipc.coffee'
 {recbar} = ipc
 import broadcast from '~/lib/broadcast.coffee'
 import ON from '~/lib/broadcast/on.coffee'
-
+import drag from '~/lib/drag.coffee'
 import config from '~/store/record.coffee'
 import {hm} from '~/lib/time.coffee'
 import DRAW from '~/store/draw.coffee'
@@ -282,6 +282,10 @@ cancel 取消录制"""
     local[i] = turn(i)

   draw = shallowRef()
+  nav = shallowRef()
+  onMounted = =>
+    draw(nav.value)
+    return

   {
     go:(en)=>
@@ -301,6 +305,7 @@ cancel 取消录制"""
       (local[en] or recbar[en])()
       return
     left
+    nav
     right
     code
     minute
```